# Combine xinit with the bash I pass as an argument, is it possible?

Tags: bash

I use PlayOnlinux for some old Win titles. I usually start the very old ones in new X window.

```
#!/bin/bash

xinit  '/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts/heroes.sh' -- :1 -ac -depth 16
```

This is the content of the actual sh file, created mostly by PlayOnLinux

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr -s 800x600

[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"
export WINEPREFIX="/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/HOMM3"
export WINEDEBUG="-all"
cd "/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/HOMM3/drive_c/./Program Files/GOG.com/Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete"
POL_Wine "Heroes3.exe"  "$@"
```

Is there a way to combine the two scripts into one, I tried forking, but kind of failed

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinit -- :1 -ac -depth 16 <<EOF

xrandr -s 800x600

[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"
export WINEPREFIX="/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/HOMM3"
export WINEDEBUG="-all"
cd "/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/HOMM3/drive_c/./Program Files/GOG.com/Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete"
POL_Wine "Heroes3.exe"  "$@"
EOF
```

If that doesn't work then try changing the `xinit` line to either of these to see if they work:

```
xinit - -- :1 -ac -depth 16 <<EOF
```

or

```
xinit /dev/stdin -- :1 -ac -depth 16 <<EOF
```

Comment: None of these 3 will work. :( Xinit will start the new X, wait for a few seconds and will exit. The actual script - the start of the game never happens.

Comment: @deckoff: Hmmm... That's odd, because the here doc is doing basically the same thing as the first script in your question.

Comment: What I just tried - the syntax of xinit is very inflexible xinit /path/script --arguments will work, though xinit --arguments /path/script will not. If I read your examples  right, the arguments are  passed before the other script is triggered.

Comment: @deckoff: The second and third variations pull the body of the script into the first argument.

Comment: For me worked third variation with /dev/stdin .